# Function to pass a list of numbers and return the average of the numbers at each iteration

Tags: python-3.x

I am working to program this function and I seem to be close. The problem is that even though I have defined y = 0, when the first loop iteration runs, y is being returned as 10. It seems to be pulling from the first number in the list, as when I change it, both i and y change.

```
def Meanlist(x):
    y = 0
    z = 1
    for i in x:        
        y += i
        Avg=(y+i)/z
        print('For Iteration', z, 'Average is', Avg)
        print('For Iteration', z, 'i is', i)
        print('For Iteration', z, 'y is', y)
        z+=1
L1 = [10, 56.7, 56, 89, 100, 99, 87.5, 34, 985, 10]
Meanlist(L1)
```

This is returning these values for the first iteration. What am I doing wrong with y? Everything else appears to be working with the function.

For Iteration 1 Average is 20.0
For Iteration 1 i is 10
For Iteration 1 y is 10

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do in your loop is

> `y += i`

In the first iteration, y is 0 but i equals to 10, so after doing "y += i", y equals to 10.
Then you do:

> `Avg=(y+i)/z`

Since y equals to 10, (y + i) equals to 20.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thanks for helping a beginner!